# Defining "eval" as a formal parameter of a Function constructor invocation. Shouldn't that throw a syntax error in strict mode code?

Tags: javascript, eval, syntax-error, strict-mode

The specification states:

> It is a SyntaxError to use within strict mode code the identifiers
>   eval or arguments as the Identifier of a FunctionDeclaration or
>   FunctionExpression or as a formal parameter name (13.1). Attempting to
>   dynamically define such a strict mode function using the Function
>   constructor (15.3.2) will throw a SyntaxError exception.

Source: http://es5.github.com/C.html#C (last bullet)

Therefore, this throws a syntax error (in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var f = function ( eval ) {};
})();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/v8Ff4/

However, this doesn't throw a syntax error:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var f = new Function( 'eval', '' );
})();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/v8Ff4/1/

It is my understanding that this second code-block should throw a syntax error. Should it? And if yes, why doesn't it?

Comment: Wait a minute, it could be that since the `new Function(...)` function executes in global code (its scope is the global scope), that the "use strict" rule doesn't apply to it. Is it that?

Comment: I don't know. Seems odd to me since "strict mode" is lexically scoped, if you add `'use strict'` at the global level, creating the function like that should inherit strict mode. Since the `eval` formal parameter is within the new environment of the function *(it isn't global)*, it seems that you should get the error.

Comment: With this: `var f = new Function( 'eval', '"use strict";' );` you get the error. But not with this: `"use strict"; var f = new Function( 'eval', ';' );` Doesn't seem right.

Comment: This run globally: `eval( 'var f = function( eval ) { ; }' );` also gives you the error.

Comment: @RightSaidFred I've figured it out. This behavior is proper and it conforms to the standard. I'll post a detailed answer later... (I can notify you if you want to)

Comment: @RightSaidFred I've posted my answer.

Comment: @gsnedders It turned out, that wasn't the reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm going to answer my own question here (since I've figured it out).

My initial premise was that both code blocks are equivalent. So that this

```
var f = function ( eval ) {};
```

is equivalent to

```
var f = new Function( 'eval', '' );
```

This is however not true. There are differences. The creation of a function object from a function declaration / expression notation is defined in [Chapter 13.2 Creating Function Objects](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2). On the other hand, the creation of a function object from a `new Function` constructor invocation is defined in [Chapter 15.3.2.1 new Function (p1, p2, … , pn, body)](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.2.1). So there are different algorithms at work here.

The specific part which is relevant to this question is the part which defines the strictness of the created function object.

**Function expressions**

The strictness of a function object created via a function expression is defined in the semantics of the production *FunctionExpression* at the beginning of chapter 13:

> Pass in true as the Strict flag if the FunctionExpression is contained
>   in strict code or if its FunctionBody is strict code.

So the function object will be strict if either one of these conditions is met:

- the function expression is contained in strict code
- the function body of the function expression is strict code

so for instance, the function `f` is strict in both examples below.

Example 1:

```
(function () {    
    var f = function () {
        'use strict';
        return 'I am strict!';
    }    
})();
```

Example 2:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';    
    var f = function () {
        return 'I am strict!';
    }    
})();
```

**Function constructor invocation**

The strictness of a function object created via a Function constructor invocation is defined in step 9 of the algorithm from Chapter 15.3.2.1 (already linked above):

> If body is strict mode code (see 10.1.1) then let strict be true, else let strict be false.

So, whether or not the `new Function` invocation is contained in strict code is **irrelevant**. To create a strict function via this pattern, one has to explicitly define the strictness in the function body (which is the last argument supplied to the constructor.

```
new Function ( 'a, b', 'return a + b;' ); // not strict
new Function ( 'a, b', '"use strict"; return a + b;' ); // strict
```

Comment: Yep, you got it. 10.1.1 *"Function code that is supplied as the last argument to the built-in Function constructor is strict function code if the last argument... begins with a Directive Prologue that contains a Use Strict Directive."* It says nothing of it being *contained in* strict mode code.